# passenger-install-nginx-module fails to install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I tried to setup my working environments as

```
rvm implode
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
source /Users/ben/.rvm/scripts/rvm

rvm get stable
rvm install 2.6.3
rvm use 2.6.3 --default

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

gem install passenger
passenger-install-nginx-module
```

But It fails when I reach to the last step (`passenger-install-nginx-module`)

```
src/cxx_supportlib/vendor-modified/boost/atomic/detail/ops_gcc_x86_dcas.hpp:408:16: error: address argument to atomic builtin cannot be
      const-qualified ('const volatile boost::atomics::detail::gcc_dcas_x86_64::storage_type *' (aka 'const volatile unsigned __int128 *')
      invalid)
        return __sync_val_compare_and_swap(&storage, value, value);
               ^                           ~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I tried to downgrade **xcode** to **10.1**, didn't work. I tried with the current version of **xcode** and didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Passenger dev here, you don't need to run `passenger-install-nginx-module` when using homebrew, just `brew install passenger nginx` and you'll get both, there are instructions for loading the nginx module in the caveats for the passenger formula.